# JMeter: Difference In Error% in JTL vs HTML Report

Tags: jmeter, performance, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

After test execution is done in NON GUI Mode and in cmd shows as Error % is 66.07%
[image]

But in JTL file shows as Total 1.68% [image]

After Generating html report manually shows same like cmd which is 66.07%
[image]

Also observed script run with 1 Vusers all the transactions are getting passed with Assertions. With 5Vusers and duration is 10 minutes observed 2 Response Assertions are getting failed randomly and error% is 66.07. when tested with 5Vusers and duration is 15 minutes observed 1 Response assertion is getting failed and error % is 20.

I don't understand why the application is behaving like this.

Don't have access to any Profiling tools to check.

Could anyone please help me here what changes needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some math together:

[image]

In the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) you have

- 3 requests total
- 2 requests failed

  ```
  2 / 3 * 100 == 66.67
  ```

so I think that JMeter calculation is correct.

The question is why you have 3 requests total and not 238. I would recommend

1. Revisiting [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) responsible for [Reporting Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)
2. Your [Transaction](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) names and the way you're exporting them for the report.